# How to mute the incoming call with single touch programatically in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c

I am having a mute button in my app,when an incoming call comes when I tap on to that button the incoming call's ringtone should become mute.

Can anyone suggest me how to do this programatically.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

Applications cannot alter core functionality of the device.  As such, you cannot interfere with the phone capabilities.  Therefore, what you are asking for is not possible.

I am, of course, assuming that you haven't jailbroken your phone.

Comment: Yes I haven't jailbroken my device.

Comment: it not posible internal function change  like if application run background at time incoming call silent  mode objective c  ?